# SSL Certification- secures subdomain on AWS s3 using Godaddy Wild Card SSL

Tags: ssl-certificate, amazon-s3, godaddy

I need to get resources.fairfuturesny.org secured. Its currently living on Amazon CloudFront S3. It's being used to host files.

I the main domain is fairfuturesny.org from godaddy, which is secured.

I purchased a wild card SSL to secure it but that was several days ago and it's still not secure. Is there a way to force the SSL by adding code index.html file or htaccess file?

The client isn't super tech-savy nor am I and I just would like a straightforward, quick and simple solution to used the wildcard ssl I paid for to secure the subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat ambiguous so it's bit difficult to answer. I'll answer the question I think you're asking, but if I've answer the wrong question please edit your question to be more precise then comment below to let me know.

If you have a static website hosted on AWS S3, with AWS CloudFront as the CDN, the easiest way to get an SSL certificate is to use AWS Certificate Manager (ACM). ACM generates a free certificate. You then configure CloudFront to use the certificate. There's a good tutorial on it [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-certificate-manager-deploy-ssltls-based-apps-on-aws/).

If you want to use the SSL certificate you paid for you can load that certificate with its private key into ACM and then CloudFront can use it. The downside of that is you will have to renew the certificate when it expires, whereas if you use ACM it would renew the certificate and set it up for you.

AWS is generally fairly complex, but in this area it's not so bad. Certificates in general are also a bit tricky.

**Update**

Better tutorial [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/). You need to follow this carefully. I strongly suggest using ACM rather than the third party certificate you purchased.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get the certificate from AWS but it wasn't registering the site as secure. But I will try and upload the one from go daddy to AWS Certificate manager, Is there a way to pull the private from godaddy?

Comment: So uploaded the Private Key to ACM and it says it's issued but the site still says not secured and I'm missing a step?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a better link. Use AWS ACM certificates. You need to carefully follow all the steps - you said you uploaded a private to ACM, that's only one step of the many required. The key steps you appear to have missed are uploading the certificate with the private key, and then configuring the CloudFront distro to use it.